# SQL - Compare all column's data from two tables efficiently

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have two tables say Table1 and Table2 with same columns and same schema structure.

Now I want to select data from Table1 which is present in Table2. However, when comparing data, I want to compare all the columns present in both these table. Like, entire record in Table1 should be present in Table2. What is the fastest and most efficient way to achieve this in SQL Server 2008? Both the tables contain around 1000-2000 records and these tables will get accessed very frequently.

Comment: this seems to be a bad database design. why do you want to keep common data in both tables at the first place.why not create a view for it that way access is faster.with this case you will have to do comparison with every row in both tables. what have you tried so far?

Comment: @vikeng21: Actually, I need to do some data cleanup activity and hence, I am creating a #temp table which is having exactly same schema as that of the actual table. Also, I have created a query to achieve above requirement using inner joins. My only concern is due to huge number of columns, I need to apply number of inner joins which might impact the performance. Hence, I was looking for more efficient way to achieve this.

Comment: but why do you need a 2nd table if you want to do data cleanup.  is it for a backup purpose which it sounds to me. please consult with the dba to see if there is some other way. i know it does deviate from the actual question but why not avoid it before going to the comparing right. you are thinking about performance and thats perfect. but i would strongly suggest consulting dba before going ahead

Answer (score 2):

The [`intersect`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188055.aspx) operator does just that:

```
SELECT *
FROM   table1
INTERSECT
SELECT *
FROM   table2
```

Answer (score 0):

With an " exists", you have a solution :

```
select * from Table1 t1 where exists (select 1 from Table2 t2  
    where t1.col1 = t2.col1
      and t1.col2 = t2.col2  
      and t1.col3 = t2.col3  
      and ...                 // check here all columns ...
   )
```

There is however a little problem in this solution in the case of null values, which can only be tested via a "IS NOT NULL" or "IS NULL", hence the complementary solution:

```
select * from Table1 t1 where exists (select 1 from Table2 t2  
    where (t1.col1 = t2.col1 or (t1.col1 IS NULL and t2.col1 IS NULL))
      and (t1.col2 = t2.col2 or (t1.col2 IS NULL and t2.col2 IS NULL))  
      and (t1.col3 = t2.col3 or (t1.col3 IS NULL and t2.col3 IS NULL))  
      and ...                 // check here all columns ...
   )
```